# Trouble with installing the 16EAGLE / getSpatialData library

Tags: r

I am trying to follow this [Processing of Sentinel-5P data within the ArcGIS platform: Creating nitrogen dioxide time series in R and ArcGIS](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-blog/processing-of-sentinel-5p-data-within-the-arcgis/ba-p/904211) and I have trouble while installing this library [16EAGLE/getSpatialData](https://github.com/16EAGLE/getSpatialData)

I tried them they give the error specified below

```
remotes::install_github("16EAGLE/getSpatialData", force=TRUE)
devtools::install_github("16EAGLE/getSpatialData", force=TRUE)
```

```
Downloading GitHub repo 16EAGLE/getSpatialData@HEAD
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                                
2: CRAN packages only                 
3: None                               
4: cli        (3.1.1  -> 3.2.0) [CRAN]
5: rlang      (0.4.11 -> 1.0.1) [CRAN]
6: tidyselect (1.1.1  -> 1.1.2) [CRAN]
7: recipes    (0.1.17 -> 0.2.0) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates: 1
cli        (3.1.1  -> 3.2.0) [CRAN]
rlang      (0.4.11 -> 1.0.1) [CRAN]
tidyselect (1.1.1  -> 1.1.2) [CRAN]
recipes    (0.1.17 -> 0.2.0) [CRAN]
Installing 4 packages: cli, rlang, tidyselect, recipes
Installing packages into ‘C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
           binary source needs_compilation
cli         3.1.1  3.2.0              TRUE
tidyselect  1.1.1  1.1.2              TRUE
recipes    0.1.17  0.2.0             FALSE

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/rlang_1.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1611345 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
Warning: restored ‘rlang’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp48qviw\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘cli’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘recipes’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/cli_3.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 493192 bytes (481 KB)
downloaded 481 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyselect_1.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 92085 bytes (89 KB)
downloaded 89 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/recipes_0.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 582287 bytes (568 KB)
downloaded 568 KB

* installing *source* package 'cli' ...
** package 'cli' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
* removing 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/cli'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/cli'
Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\name\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\00LOCK-cli\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll to C:\Users\name\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll: Permission denied
* installing *source* package 'tidyselect' ...
** package 'tidyselect' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.11 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.1 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tidyselect'
* removing 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/tidyselect'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/tidyselect'
* installing *source* package 'recipes' ...
** package 'recipes' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'dplyr' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace 'rlang' 0.4.11 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'recipes'
* removing 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/recipes'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/recipes'

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp48qviw\downloaded_packages’
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp48qviw\remotes44d8f04e5f\16EAGLE-getSpatialData-269d4ea/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'getSpatialData': (1s)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'getSpatialData_0.1.1.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'getSpatialData' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.11 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'getSpatialData'
* removing 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/getSpatialData'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/name/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/getSpatialData'
Warning messages:
1: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\name\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\00LOCK\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to C:\Users\name\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
2: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘cli’ had non-zero exit status
3: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘tidyselect’ had non-zero exit status
4: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status
5: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp48qviw/file44d84f8e64f5/getSpatialData_0.1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Specified the `lib=` but still got the error.

Additionally, I downloaded the package as a .zip file from the git hub and tried to install it manually. The package was installed but when I run the library I got an error again;

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘getSpatialData’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.11 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
```

Can someone help with this?
Is the problem the way I do as uploading the package or the package itself?

Comment: How are you running R? Because it looks like at the point you are updating packages that it already has loaded a bunch of them and maybe Windows has locked the files so the update fails. If you can run R and do this as the very first thing, before any of those packages are loaded, then it might work. Or choose the "None" option to not update any of the requirements at this point - they are only "recommended" and that usually means they aren't a necessity.

Comment: By "How are you running R?" I mean is this run from inside an ArcGIS Pro session, after ArcGIS might have done a load of setup, or is it R run from the Windows command line or by running from a Windows R icon or menu item? Or from RStudio?

Comment: I am running R by using RStudio.

Comment: Based on the @Spacedman suggestion, I deleted R and R studio and reinstall it again and reinstall the package saying no to the dependencies and it works.